# bokeh: widget to switch between figures/plots

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

Hi is there a way in bokeh to switch between plots, something like this:

[image]

So that when I click on "plot 1" I'll get the first plot, and when I click "plot 2" I'll see the second plot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using tabs is what you mean, yes they are supported.

The docs contain multiple examples. A simple one is located here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/layouts.html#bokeh.models.layouts.Tabs

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! I did searched for it, but did not manage to find.

Comment: Great, not a problem. If you can also mark the answer as correct to help others that would be great.

Comment: I'll do, but StackOverflow needs more time. Maybe you can add the code from the html, so that your answer will have the complete solution (including the html example)

Comment: Thats ok. I dont think the code needs to be added in since it will be a literal copy paste and nothing original.